# Show List in xaml using ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a UserControl called "UserControllerIo" and this is what it has:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Messages { get; set; }
        public UserControllerIo()
        {
            Messages = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            InitializeComponent();
            IoComponentViewModel.Instance = new IoComponentViewModel();
            Label1.DataContext = IoComponentViewModel.Instance;
            Messages.Add(Label1.Text);
        }
```

I consume this in my xml like so:

```
<Grid>
        <Label>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Label1" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                       Text="{Binding Path=XState, Mode=OneWay}">
            </TextBlock>
        </Label>
         <ListView 
             x:Name="ListView"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" />   
    </Grid>
```

I have a view model for this control:

```
class IoComponentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public static IoComponentViewModel Instance { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string _xState;

        public string XState
        {
            get { return _xState; }
            set
            {
                _xState = value;
                OnPropertyChanged($"XState");
            }
        }

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

And I invoke to populate the list on another class like so:

```
case x:
IoComponentViewModel.Instance.XState = msg;
break;
```

My problem is, it is not showing in my Listview although I can see it in my label. How can I achieve this?

Comment: So let me just check I'm understanding this, you are changing the value of `XState` but expecting the list value to also update?

Comment: If there's only one column, use a listbox. Here's a quite similar working example:  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32164.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-2.aspx

Comment: The ItemsSource Binding has no source object. Try `ItemsSource="{Binding Messages, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`. Even then, calling `Messages.Add(Label1.Text);` in the constructor might be too early, since the Label's Text property might not yet be set.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much I understood your task from the provided code, but look at this implementation variant.

**IoComponentViewModel**:

```
public class IoComponentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static IoComponentViewModel Instance { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _xState;

    public string XState
    {
        get { return _xState; }
        set
        {
            if (_xState == value)
                return;

            XStates.Add(_xState = value);
            OnPropertyChanged($"XState");
            
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> XStates { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**XAML**:

```
<Grid x:Name="PART_Grid">
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:IoComponentViewModel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--<Label>-->
        <TextBlock x:Name="Label1" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                   Text="{Binding XState, Mode=OneWay}">
        </TextBlock>
    <!--</Label>-->
    <ListView Grid.Row="1"
         x:Name="ListView"
             ItemsSource="{Binding XStates}" />
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind**:

```
    //public ObservableCollection<string> Messages { get; set; }
    public UserControllerIo()
    {
        //Messages = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        InitializeComponent();
        // IoComponentViewModel.Instance = new IoComponentViewModel();
        //Label1.DataContext = IoComponentViewModel.Instance;
        IoComponentViewModel.Instance = (IoComponentViewModel)PART_Grid.DataContext;
        //Messages.Add(Label1.Text);
    }
```

Comment: There may also be such a reason for the error.
In UserControl you create one instance of IoComponentViewModel, and in IoComponentViewModel.Instance.XState = msg; you are turning to another.

Check if you happen to change the IoComponentViewModel.Instance property somewhere in the code?

Answer (score -1):

I misread the question initially. There are two problems. Your list is not binding to the view model, so you need an element reference.

```
<UserControl x:Class="StackOverflow.UserControllerIo"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
         x:Name="MyUserControl"
         >
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label>

    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" x:Name="Label1" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
               Text="{Binding Path=XState, Mode=OneWay}">
    </TextBlock>
    </Label>

    <ListView  Grid.Row="1"
        x:Name="ListView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Messages, ElementName=MyUserControl}" >

    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Secondly, at the point where you add Label1.Text to your data binding is not ready. So you will need to wait for binding  before you read the text, for example in load event like this:

```
    public partial class UserControllerIo : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Messages { get; set; }
    public UserControllerIo()
    {
        Messages = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        InitializeComponent();
        IoComponentViewModel.Instance = new IoComponentViewModel();
        Label1.DataContext = IoComponentViewModel.Instance;

        IoComponentViewModel.Instance.XState = "Something";
        

        Loaded += UserControllerIo_Loaded;

    }
    private void UserControllerIo_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Messages.Add(Label1.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:**

**my first tests mislead me, by testing with an int property for adding values to the List on runtime.
ObservableCollection updates anyway!**

The problem is how you declared the Messages Property. If you have a Property on a Control it needs to be a dependency Property to notify the UI.

replace

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Messages { get; set; }
```

with

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Messages
{
  get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(MessagesProperty); }
  set { SetValue(MessagesProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MessagesProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Messages", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(UserControllerIo), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

and you should be fine.

OR

you could imlpement INotifyPropertyChanged on your UserControl class.

And don't forget to maintain @Clemens' comment about binding!!!

`ItemsSource="{Binding Messages, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}`